# Filtering directories when parsing cpp files in get-includes in python bindings/clang

Tags: python, c++, parsing, include, clang

I should write a python-clang parser which returns all the inclusions in cpp files.
So I use sth like the following code:

```
def _main():
    from clang.cindex import Index
    from optparse import OptionParser

    filter=['/usr/lib','usr/include']
    p=OptionParser()
    (o,a)=p.parse_args()
    i=Index.create()
    t=i.parse(None,a)
    for i in t.get_includes():
        print i.include

if __name__=='__main__':
    _main()
```

Now i need to filter just some of inclusions like specific directories:

```
filter=['/usr/lib','usr/include']
```

Question 1: I would like to know how this filtering is possible and how my code should change?

Question 2: How to make a config file to include all these filter direstories in that instead of just writting them hardcoded?

to run the test: you need to have a cpp file like:

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include"ex1.h"

  int main(){
      return 0;
  }
```

and *.h file:

```
 #include<QMap>
```

run:

```
./python-clang.py ex1.cpp
```

sample of results:

```
 /usr/include/pthread.h
 /usr/include/sched.h
 /usr/include/time.h
 /usr/include/bits/sched.h
 /usr/include/time.h
 /usr/include/bits/time.h
 /usr/include/signal.h
 /usr/include/bits/sigset.h
 /usr/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
 /usr/include/bits/setjmp.h
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
 /usr/include/unistd.h
 /usr/include/bits/posix_opt.h
 /usr/include/bits/environments.h
 /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
 /usr/include/bits/confname.h
 /usr/include/getopt.h
 /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/bits      /atomic_word.h
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4/bits/locale_classes.h
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4/string
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4/bits/allocator.h
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4/ext/new_allocator.h
```

Comment: You want to exclude the directories in `filter` from the results?

Comment: yes, exactly! i want to exclude some of the includes from the list of the results..like directories which start with '/usr/lib'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your `for` loop:

```
...
for i in t.get_includes():
    if not i.include in filter:
        print i.include
...
```

As for the config file containing the exclusions. You could do something like this:

```
def _main():
    ...
    with open('/path/to/file/ignore.txt') as f:
        filter = f.readlines()
    ...
```

Then in `ignore.txt`:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/include
...
```

#### UPDATE

Based on your comments and edits to your question.

```
def _main():
    ...
    with open('/path/to/file/ignore.txt') as f:
        ignore = map(lambda l: l.strip(), f.readlines())

    for i in t.get_includes():
        if not i.include.startswith(ignore):
            print i.include
```

Couple of things to note here.

1. I've changed the variable name `filter` to `ignore` since `filter`
   is a built-in type.
2. The lines in `ignore.txt` are having the `\n` stripped and mapped to
   a `tuple` instead of a `list` so they can be used with the
   `startswith` method when being read.
3. You could also use list comprehension to put the *filtered* results
   into a list to be used later.

`results = [i.include for i in t.get_includes() if not i.startswith(ignore)]`

Comment: Thanks, easy approach, actually I thought that I could get use of some methods in cindex.py! one other question how to make a config file to include all these filter direstories in that instead of just writting them hardcoded?

Comment: this answer seems to be the correct one, but I still see exclude ones in the result!!

Comment: Can you include a sample of the results?

Comment: tnx, strip works and also i had to add str(i.include) in filter. i.include was not String...